# Issues with broker database deployment

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, publishing

Scenario: In the deployer server side the storage config file is configured for file system storage for pages and binaries and database storage for all the rest.

I am using the deployer windows service to do the work.

The config files seems to be OK (compared with the same files in the others environments).

A strange issue: the deployer can deploy to the file system, but nothing happens in the broker database side.

- In the publish queue all seems to be OK (success). The details view
  shows all the publication steps with sucess state.
- Nothing in the Tridion event log.
- Nothing in the CM server logs (logback configured to ALL).

Finally in the core log file in the deployer server (logback configured to ALL), I have found out a brief reference (no error) to license file or binding configuration (I will back and post, if I can recover it, the complete message).

After check some configurations, etc., including place a sniffer to catch communications betweens deployer server and broker database (I have been racking my brain for awhile), finally, I have decided to check the cd_licenses file in the deployer server, "a priori" does not seem to make any sense for me because the file system deployment works fine. But surprisingly there was a mistake in the license file...

And now the questions:

- Have I searched the error info in the wrong places? Shouldn't we
  have been able to see this error more plainly?
- Someone could explain me in which moment the content delivery license
  is validated?
- Why the file system deployment have been worked?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1) No, but see my answer to 3

2) the license file is validated, minimally, on initialization, which for the deployer is on start up (for other use cases it might be per session/request)

3) the deployer supports deployment to the file system as a default (legacy support), hence with a faulty key it worked. As this is intended behavior you did not see an error

Comment: Thanks Julian for the clarification. I cannot avoid to think that this kind of behaviour could be a source of problems. Not to mention the fact that someone could deploy the website (at least partially) without a valid content delivery license.

Comment: certainly this is true. But it's difficult to know when to show an error and when not to in this case.

Answer (score 7):

In response to question 3, this is taken from [the online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_80832329C62445E2958E3E6485908760) (login required):

> If your license for database storage is expired or missing, Content
>   Delivery stores content on the file system as a fallback scenario.

If you have more than one file system storage location in your cd_storage_conf.xml file (probable if you are publishing more than one site from Tridion), then you can specify which one to use as the default fallback location with the `defaultStorage` attribute on the Storage node.

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="my_site" defaultFilesystem="false" defaultStorage="true">
    <Root Path="D:\Websites" />
</Storage>
```